# How should I achieve background color of button with ripple effect

Tags: android

I am trying to implement ripple effect in my android application, I imeplemented the ripple effect on button but I don't know how exactly I should change the button color when is not focused/pressed.

my `ripple.xml` is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="#f816a463"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#f816a463" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

and my button is this:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Login"
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_below="@+id/password"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:elevation="2dp" />
```

I have tryed to create a selector and set the normal state of button with a color and the `state_pressed` `state_focused` to the `ripple.xml` but it didn't work.

One more solution to achieve this is to wrap the button into a `Layout` with 0 margins and set the layout color but I don't like this solution. Is there a smarter way how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `android:id="@android:id/mask"` from your `<item>` like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="#f816a463"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#f816a463" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```